# Text calculated column filtered by value condition (power bi)

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

Hey guys can someone help me out with this please:

I have several Stock IDs from enterprises, being that an enterprise could have just a single value for its Stock ID, as well as various, having always a base of 4 initial letters (for example the enterprise with the Stock ID "AHEB" has AHEB3, AHEB5 and AHEB6).

My goal is to create a calculated column that already filters these IDs by negotiability (only the most negotiated ID for each enterprise should remain in this column).  I'm sending a pbix example of the problem: https://file.io/SwSi19PQGZgv

Creating a new column with just the 4 initial letters as I did in the following example would be perfect for my other purposes if it showed also the rest of the ID (numbers/letters).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mexvK.png)

Tks!

Comment: File link no longer works.

Comment: How do you measure 'negotiability'? What determines that one ID is more negotiated than the other?

Comment: Hi Clifford! In fact it's something that doesn't follow a rule, but I got the solution! I'll post it here, thank you for your disposition!

Answer (score 0):

I created these three formulas, and filtered my slicer with a Top N visual level filter, adding the variable "FILTERSTOCK" to it, so that it would filter only the Stock Codes that correspond to "TRUE". Here are the formulas:

1. last negotiated value column =

VAR RESULT =
CALCULATE(
LASTNONBLANKVALUE('Database'[Date],max('Database'[negotiated value]))
)
RETURN RESULT

2. MaxValuePerStock =
   VAR CurrentStock = max('Stock Codes'[Stock without numbers/letters])
   VAR RESULT =
   CALCULATE(
   [last negotiated value column],
   FILTER(ALL('Stock Codes'), 'Stock Codes'[Stock without numbers/letters] = CurrentStock)
   )
   RETURN RESULT
3. FILTERSTOCK = if([last negotiated value column]=[MaxValuePerStock],
   TRUE(),
   BLANK())